# SQLite query returns values twice

Tags: php, sqlite, foreach

The SQL table consists of:

```
names:  id | firstName | lastName
phones: id | phone1    | phone2   | phone3
```

The task is to show the registered users' first & last names. Then, according to users' ID, show phone numbers (if they exist). In addition, I need to have an opportunity to expand the 'phones' table, so I can't just use string join because I am not aware of the amount of numbers.

IMHO, it can be solved with foreach loop:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare( 'SELECT firstName, lastName, id FROM names');
$stmt->execute();
foreach($stmt as $row)
{

    $stmt = $connection->prepare( 'SELECT phone1, phone2, phone3 FROM phones WHERE id=?');
    $stmt->execute([$row['id']]);
    $number_str = '';

    foreach($stmt as $numbers)  // for each user's array of phones
    {
        foreach($numbers as $number) {  // for each phone in the array
            if($number) {
                $number_str .= $number . ', ';  // build a string "phone1, phone2, phone3"
            }
        }
    }
    array_push($users, new User($row['firstName'], $row['lastName'], substr($number_str, 0, -2)));  // filling the array
```

Unfortunately, each user's number_str looks like: phone1, phone1, phone2, phone2 etc.

Update:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare( 'SELECT firstName, lastName, id FROM names');
$stmt->execute();
foreach($stmt as $row) {

    $stmt1 = $connection->prepare('SELECT phone1, phone2, phone3 FROM phones WHERE id=?');
    $stmt1->execute([$row['id']]);
    $a = $stmt1->fetch();

    $number_str = $a[0].$a[1].$a[2]; // phone1phone2phone3  -- works FINE, but why? btw, count($a) is 6, but I can't access $a[3]
    $number_str = implode(', ', $a); // phone1, phone1, etc

    array_push($users, new User($row['firstName'], $row['lastName'], $number_str));  // filling the array
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with that nested `foreach($stmt as $numbers)` and `foreach($numbers as $number)`?

Comment: Each user has 3 or more (in the future) phone numbers. First, I get each user's numbers array, and then I transform the numbers array to an appropriate string.

Comment: Simply [fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) the row and then [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the resulting array.

Comment: Re: your update; change `$a = $stmt1->fetch();` to `$a = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);` or `$a = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`.  The default is BOTH, with will basically double the raw array entries

Answer (score 0):

I pretty sure that you need to fetch the result and then you will receive the expected result.

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare( 'SELECT firstName, lastName, id FROM names');
$stmt->execute();
$namesResult = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($namesResult as $row)
{

    $stmt1 = $connection->prepare( 'SELECT phone1, phone2, phone3 FROM phones WHERE id=?');
    $stmt1->execute([$row['id']]);
    $number_str = '';
    $result = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($result as $numbers)
    {
        foreach($numbers as $number) {
            if($number) {
                $number_str .= $number . ', ';
            }
        }
    array_push($users, new User($row['firstName'], $row['lastName'], substr($number_str, 0, -2)));  // filling the array
    }
```

Comment: I get lots of "Illegal string offset 'firstName' in" and "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in "

Comment: I updated the answer, you need to put the array_push in the first loop scope.

Comment: I even tried to create a new database, fill it with 1 person:
1 aaa bbb
1 123 (null) (null)
and just SELECT * FROM numbers.
It showed 123, 123, , , , ,